# Call `require` inside a loop only executes once

Tags: ruby, require

I have a script to run all tests in a directory, using `require`; I do:

```
Dir.files.each
...
```

and then

```
require 'path'
...
```

I try to use another loop to run those tests a few times, passing different arguments. I have my arguments in an array, and I go through the array, then run the same code as above to run all tests in a directory. In this loop, I print a line:

```
puts executing tests for a[i]
```

and the next line is the `require` that runs the set of tests.
The problem is that the print executes e.g., ten times (ten lines printed together), but `require` only runs in the end, passing only the very last element of the array. I tried different statements, and they all run fine, so I don't believe it's a problem in the loop; I think it's the `require`. I tried `load`, but didn't see any difference. 'exec' only runs the first test in the set. Any ideas?

some more details:

thanks for the replies! the system command is much closer to what I wanted - it runs all tests for me.

I have below an example of what I'm trying to do.
When I run the script once passing specific arguments 'a', I get the following results:

```
#### Run all tests for 'a' ####
Loaded suite
............................
Finished in 220.123 seconds
```

If I put my arguments in an array eg. ar = ['a','b','c','d']
I get

```
#### Run all tests for 'a' ####
#### Run all tests for 'b' ####
#### Run all tests for 'c' ####
#### Run all tests for 'd' ####
Loaded suite 
............................
Finished in 220.123 seconds
```

ie. the tests run for the last option only (d)

If I use 'system' every single file runs individually - which makes it hard to go through the results for say 100 tests for a few different runs.

The code snippet is :

```
  for i in 0 .. @ar.length-1 do
      puts'##  Running : '+ @ar[i] + '  ##' 
      Dir.entries('./suite_dir').each do | file |
          require './suite_dir/'+ file
      end
  end
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your program does? Maybe write a short example that has the same (undesired) behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `require` like that, it's not intended to be executable...it only works once.

From **http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require**

> `require(name)` → true or false
>
> Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the
>   feature is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to run all files from the directory:

```
Dir.foreach(path) do |file|
  puts "Testing #{file}"
  system(path+file)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I use 'system' though, every single file runs individually - which makes it hard to go through the results for say 100 tests for a few different runs.